# Solving the system with $\frac{\omega_{lb1}}{\omega_{ln1}}=12.6$ and $\arctan\frac2{\omega_{lb1}} - \arctan\frac2{\omega_{ln1}}=-6^\circ$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

So, in our Control Engineering classes, in the presentation about synthesizing a regulator using Bode plot (using lead compensation and lag compensation), we have the following system of equations:

$$\frac{\omega_{lb1}}{\omega_{ln1}} = 12.6$$
$$\arctan \left(\frac{2}{\omega_{lb1}} \right) - \arctan \left( \frac{2}{\omega_{ln1}} \right) = -6^\circ$$

Allegedly, the solution is:

$$\omega_{lb1} = 0.2 \text{rad/sec}$$
$$\omega_{ln1} = 0.016 \text{rad/sec}$$

But how can that system of equations be solved?

Comment: I see degrees , rad and seconds ... That is confusing. physics ??
Plz use rad units for trig, it will also help you.

Comment: Hint: Solve for one variable in the first equation (there's a clear choice), and then use the formula for the tangent of a difference.

Comment: Using Sean Roberson's suggestion, you will get a quadratic in the variables.
Also, it is easier if you make the variables $a$ and $b$ and the constants $u$ and $v$ (or vice versa - it doesn't matter and it reduces the chances for errors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's time to present a solution. I'm going to use the variables $a$ and $b$ instead of the subscripted $\omega$, and I'll let $T = \tan(-6^\circ) = \tan \left( -\frac{\pi}{30} \right)$ (just to get everything in radians). Now the easiest thing to do is to notice $a = 12.6b$ and we can just substitute into the second equation:

$$ \arctan \left( \frac{2}{12.6b} \right) - \arctan \left( \frac{2}{b} \right) = -\frac{\pi}{30}. $$

Now we'll do something a little clever. Remember that the inverse tangent function returns angles. So what happens when we take tangents on both sides of the above? Well, we need to use the tangent difference formula. Namely,

$$ \tan (u - v) = \frac{\tan u - \tan v}{1 + \tan u \tan v}. $$

So now by taking tangents (and cleaning up), we get

$$ \frac{2(b - 12.6b)}{4 + 12.6b^2} = T $$

and we can rearrange this to be the friendlier quadratic equation

$$ 12.6Tb^2 + 23.2b + 4T = 0 $$

which yields the roots $b = 0.01814$ and $b = 17.5004$ (as seen on my TI-Nspire). We then get $a = 0.228567$ and $a = 220.505$. You can then pick out the solutions that make sense in your application.

(SciPy's routines for numerical solutions to a nonlinear system of equations agree with this, as does MATLAB.)